# Assembly subb loop

Tags: assembly

I'm trying to figure out what this portion of assembly code does.  It was decompiled from an .o file, and I do not have the source code.

I believe this code should loop infinitely because %eax is decreased by 4 each iteration, it should never be equal to the break case `%eax == 0x18`

```
00000000 <_funct>"
0:    push    %ebp                /set up stack for function
1:    mov     %esp,%ebp           /
3:    mov     $0x0,%eax           / assign 0 to %eax
8:    subb    $0x4, 0x0(%eax)     / subtract 4 from %eax which is stored into %eax
f:    inc     $eax                / add 1 to %eax which is stored into %eax
10:   cmp     $0x18,%eax          / if %eax is not equal to 0x18
13:   jne     8 <_funct+0x8>      /   go to subb command
15:   leave                       / return from function
16:   ret                         /
```

How does this code not enter an infinite loop?

Comment: Also, did I interpret the subb 0x4, 0x0(%eax) correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `subb    $0x4, 0x0(%eax)` has a memory reference, it's subtracting from the memory location pointed to by `eax`. The `eax` register itself is not affected by this instruction.

As such, this loop subtracts 4 from 24 (`=0x18`) consecutive memory locations.

PS: That seems to be output from `objdump`. You might want to run it with `-dr` flags to see relocation entries. I suspect the `0x0` will be some offset, as otherwise this would blow up due to null pointer.

Comment: So it subtracts 4 from the first 24(0x18) memory locations? As in it starts at location 0x00 and advances?

Comment: Corect, i didn't pay attention to `0x0(%eax)`, i mostly read the comments.